# Codeigniter and decrypt in a foreach loop not working as expected

Tags: php, codeigniter

So i have encrypted values which i'm pulling onto a view via a controller and model.
The values are displaying encrypted in the view output.
But when i try and decrypt the query values i'm not getting anything returned.

It was originally in a table which i have now stripped back to the query row values.
So just for testing, this works fine as I wanted to make sure the encryption functions were working:

```
      <?php
      $plain_text = 'This is a plain-text message!';
      $ciphertext = $this->encryption->encrypt($plain_text);
        echo $ciphertext. '<br>';
        // Outputs: This is a plain-text message!
        echo $this->encryption->decrypt($ciphertext);     
      ?>
```

but this doesnt give any output:

```
                <?php 
                foreach ($data->result() as $systemadmin)
                {
                  echo $this->encryption->decrypt($systemadmin->TC_FIRST_NAME);
                }
                ?>
```

I know the encryption is functioning as I was able to encrypt the data going into the table.
But when I try looping through the query object, it doesn't want to know.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Matt

Comment: Is there an error? Or just, no output?

Comment: try $systemadmin['TC_FIRST_NAME'] maybe, just a guess, maybe im totally wrong

Comment: @Rustyjim No error just doesn't output anything onscreen

Comment: $systemadmin->TC_FIRST_NAME has a value?

Comment: @Rustyjim This is array notation $systemadmin['TC_FIRST_NAME'] so that wouldn't work as its a query object being returned

Comment: @Rustyjim yes when i dont add the decrypt then this will return a value $systemadmin->TC_FIRST_NAME

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214617/discussion-between-rustyjim-and-jeepers-creepers).